# Finding the value of K

Tags: vectors

$$π1:( 1+k , -3 , 6 )$$

$$π2: ( 1 , 5+k , 3k)$$

Does anyone know the values of k that would make these parallel and perpendicular, ive been trying for hours but nothing seems to work

The original equation is

$$π1:(1+k)x−3y+6z−4=0$$

$$π2:x+(5+k)y+3kz+1=0$$

Comment: For these to be parallel, you need a number $k$ and a value $c$ with $c = 1+k, c(5+k) = -3, c(3k) = 6$. So $c = 2/k$, and you get $2/k = 1 + k$ and $2(5 + k) = -3k$, so $10 + 2k = -3k$, and that makes $k = -2$. To be perpendicular, the dot product of $(1+k, -3, 6)$ and $(1, 5+k, 3k)$ must be zero. Can you compute that dot product in terms of $k$?

Comment: @JohnHughes yea I already got to that step but im not sure how to solve it after

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are perpendicular, $v_1 \cdot v_2 = 0$.
- If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are parallel, $v_2 = av_2$ for some constant $a$.

Comment: yes, I already know that but none of the values are working @mattDs17

Comment: For the first one, I'm getting $k = \frac{7}{8}$. Surely you don't mean you're looking for a $k$ which makes them both perpendicular _and_ parallel?

Comment: no no two separate values for k, one value of k will make it perpendicular and one value of k will make it parallel @mattDs17